# Javascript appear in title tag

Tags: javascript

is it possible to have javascript appear in the title tag on a web page?

Cheers

Jules

Comment: You want to show code in the title or what does *javascript appear in the title tag* mean?

Comment: @saj, you mean [the magazine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vogue_%28magazine%29)?

Answer (score 2):

No. From the HTML-specification [(Section *7.4.2 The TITLE element*)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.4.2):

> *Titles may contain character entities (for accented characters, special characters, etc.), but **may not contain other markup** (including comments). [...]*

This is what you get in Firefox for instance:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn’t normally “appear” anywhere. However, the [title element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-title-element-0) can only contain text, not markup, so if you insert a script tag there it will be displayed literally.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming what you want to do is to use javascript to alter what's being displayed in the title bar. That can still be achieved by setting `document.title` - although not from within the actual `<title>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
<title>javascript !!</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

`No` .. as per my knowledge you can;t add javascript to a title tag